# PHP and JS Autocomplete is not working in laravel blade in vscode

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, settings

Im using vscode and working on laravel project, but php autocomplete is not working even inside `@php @endphp` or not even `{{ }}`, and javascript autocomplete also not working in blade files inside `<script></script>`. I used **phpstorm** but that is paid and i have installed many extensions in vscode to get the result i want but nothing works

here is my settings

```json
{
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
  // "workbench.productIconTheme": "a-file-icon-vscode-product-icon-theme",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.lineHeight": 1.6,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "codeium.enableSearch": true,
  "editor.fontFamily": " 'monospace', monospace",
  "better-comments.tags": [

    {
      "tag": "!!",
      "color": "#F6FF33",
      "strikethrough": false,
      "backgroundColor": "transparent"
    },
    {
      "tag": "?",
      "color": "#3498DB",
      "strikethrough": false,
      "backgroundColor": "transparent"
    },
    {
      "tag": "TODO",
      "color": "#0073ff", 
      "strikethrough": false,
      "backgroundColor": "transparent"
    },
    {
      "tag": "//",
      "color": "#68FF33",
      "strikethrough": false,
      "backgroundColor": "transparent"
    },
    {
      "tag": "**",
      "color": "#FF33EC",
      "strikethrough": false,
      "backgroundColor": "transparent"
    }
  ],
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.fontWeight": "normal",
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "bootstrapAutocomplete.version": "4.6",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "a-file-icon-vscode",
  "[php]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client"
  },
  "intelephense.telemetry.enabled": false,
  "intelephense.completion.triggerParameterHints": true,
  "intelephense.completion.insertUseDeclaration": true,
  "intelephense.trace.server": "messages",
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedClassConstants": false,
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedFunctions": false,
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedConstants": false,
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedProperties": false,
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes": false,
  "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedMethods": false,
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {},
  "console-ninja.featureSet": "Community",
  "bootstrapIntelliSense.version": "Bootstrap v4.6",
  "codeium.enableConfig": {
    "enabled": true,
    "keybindings": {
      
    }
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
  },
  "editor.fontSize": 15,
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 13
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most common causes

1. Conflicting JavaScript Libraries:
   -> Conflicts between several JavaScript libraries can occasionally cause autocomplete to malfunction. To isolate the problem, try deactivating any extra JavaScript libraries or plugins.
2. Missing jQuery Libraries:
   -> Autocomplete for JavaScript elements and Blade directives often depends on the jQuery and jQuery UI frameworks. Ensure that your project incorporates these libraries correctly. Include the minified versions from your project's public directory or use CDN URLs.
3. Incorrect File Association:
   -> Make sure that Blade files are properly associated with HTML in your IDE or text editor. You can add the following configuration to your Visual Studio Code settings.JSON document:
   {"files.associations":{"*.blade.php": "html"}}

Comment: The question is about PHP autocomplete in VScode, 1. and 2. are irrelevant for this

Comment: @brombeer i believe the 1 and 2 are referring to `javascript autocomplete also not working in blade files`

Comment: @Adi "Autocomplete of Javascript functions/variables in `<script>` tags inside a `.blade.php` file in VSCode" is what I got from that sentence

Comment: Plus, the question's title is "_PHP and JS Autocomplete is not working in laravel blade in vscode_"

Comment: I modified the question after answering.

Comment: You mean the question has been modified after you answered? I'll give you that, but the mention of "visual-studio-code" and "php-storm" should have made it clear that this is about VSCode autocomplete